# Linq to Entities, Inject Join Inside Query Expression

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to improve the performance for some of our LINQ queries and there is one little thing that has a lot of space for improvement: joins. 
Almost all my queries have some join that is used to filter the result, but are not selected into de result. And these filtering conditions are optional...

What I have today is something like:

```
var q = from t1 in context.Set<T1>() 
    where t1.mandatoryfilter >= 0
    select t1;

if (useFilter) 
{
    var q2 = from t1 in q
        from t2 in context.Set<T2>().Where(t2 => t2.fk == t1.pk).DefaultIfEmpty
        where t2.filterProperty == filterValue
        select t1;

    if (useFilter2) 
    {
        [...]

        return q3.ToList();
    }

    return q2.ToList();
} 
else 
{
    if (useFilter2) 
    {
        [...]

        return q2.ToList();
    }

    return q.ToList();
}
```

This will generate a projection of the query. And depending on the complexity/quantity of the filters it will generate more and more projections and the code need to be nested if I need to combine some of the filters. The resulting query can grow to a size where it gets too large to send over the internet (not actually too large XD but it becomes a performance issue) and the code itself gets hard to maintain.

I know I could just change back to string SQL... but that is not a very elegant solution is it?

I'd like to know if there is a way to inject the join and the filter directly do the Expression Tree, so the provider would not generate the projections and the code would be linear and simple.

ps.: very important information, I'm using EF6, Linq-to-Entities, default SqlClient.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too confident with the query-syntax version of LINQ, and don't have VS open, so I'm using the method-syntax to make sure I get it correct: but the same idea applies.

This is a fairly standard way of applying filters. You don't create new queries each time, you simply append a predicate for each filter. Works for joins too (and unless you're using a custom join you likely don't need to explicitly use `.Join`)

```
var people = context.Set<Person>()
                .Where(p => p.mandatoryFilter > 0);

if (filter.WithAddress != null)
    people = people.Where(p => p.Address == filter.WithAddress);

if (filter.WithBossName != null)
    people = people.Where(p => p.Boss.Name == filter.WithBossName);

return people.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use navigation properties you hardly ever need joins and you can apply most filter conditions as a single expression.

Let's suppose your `T1` entity has a navigation property `T2`. The filter expression will look like this:

```
q = q.Where(q.T2.filterProperty1 == filterProperty == filterValue);
```

You also see here that you can just append an expression to the existing query `q`.

Now it turns into a commonly applied pattern to add filter conditions to an `IQueryable`:

```
IQueryable<T1> query = from t1 in context.Set<T1>() 
                       where t1.mandatoryfilter >= 0
                       select t1;

if (filterValue2 != null)
    query = query.Where(t => t.T2.filterProperty == filterValue2);
if (filterValue3 != null)
    query = query.Where(t => t.T3.filterProperty == filterValue3);
if (filterValue4 != null)
    query = query.Where(t => t.T4.filterProperty == filterValue4);
```

(Note that `query` should be cast to `IQueryable`, otherwise the assignments `query = query....` don't compile.)

And now you can even apply filters to 1:n associations

```
if (filterValue5 != null)
    query = query.Where(t => t.T5s.Any(t5 => t5.filterProperty == filterValue5));
```

You can't do this if you use `join` for filtering, because it would multiply the result set.

Comment: Even using the query= query.where it will generate a projection for that. And some times it will put the filter inside the projection.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. A "projection" is basically the columns you see in the `SELECT` clause. I don't see how these predicates have any influence on the `SELECT` clause. You will always *only* select columns from T1.

Comment: When I say projection I mean an SQL projection on the generated SQL. Something like:
SELECT a.column1, a.column2 from (select a.column1, a.column2 from table a where <clause 1>) where <clause 2>

Comment: That's a sub query. You can ignore it as an implementation detail. It has no influence on the result set.